# Kicking off multiple processes in a Windows Service

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using nssm to install a Windows batch file as a service.  It would be nice if I could kick off two processes within this batch file, which I believe is done using 'start'.

Say, I do manage to get my service installed with two processes running...What happens to those processes if I restart the service?  What happens if one process throws and exception?

Are there any tutorials or documentation that talk about issues like this in further detail?

Comment: When your batch file starts, it can check to see if it's already running and if it is, you can kill the other one OR exit

Comment: According to the documentation, NSSM will monitor subprocesses (as well as the main process) and kill them when the service is stopped.